# Does Google Tag Manager Make My Real Time count double in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

This week I encounter a weird real time number in my google analytics. The real time number is about 1000 while the active pages is just about 500.

This happens after I put a custom tag manager to track pageviews from each author (with datalayer).

There's no additional GA script in the app. The only script is:

```
<script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src='https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);})(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-xxxxxxxx');</script>
```

And then immediately after that (I was wondering if this is the cause):

```
<script>
        dataLayer = [];
        function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
        gtag('js', new Date());
        gtag('config', 'UA-xxxxxxxxxx-x');
        gtag('config', 'GA_TRACKING_ID', {
          'custom_map': {'dimension1': 'Author'}
        });
      </script>
```

Is this behavior normal? Or did I set something wrong?